# WSASend for UDP socket triggers FD_READ when no destination available

Tags: c++, mfc, network-programming, winsock2

I'm writing C++ code for UDP socket class to handle basic operations (such as connect, send and receive data). I try using network events mechanism with WSAEventSelect for these basic operations associated with the socket.
When I use WSASend to send data to a (UDP) destination that receives the data everything goes well.
However, when I use WSASend to send data to a destination that does not exist (UDP) or is not reachable through the network I get the FD_READ event triggered. This of course causes serious problems since there is no actual data to receive !!

I can't explain why is this happening - any ideas ?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong, Here are relevant parts of my code:

```
WSADATA m_wsaData ;         
SOCKET  m_Socket ;          
WSAEVENT    m_SocketEvent ;

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &m_wsaData) != 0)
{
// some error
}

// Create a new socket to receive datagrams on
struct addrinfo hints, *res = NULL ;
int rc ;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)) ;
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC ;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM ;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP ;

rc = getaddrinfo("SomePC", "3030", &hints, &res) ;

if(rc == WSANO_DATA)
{
    // some error
}

if ((m_Socket = WSASocket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol, NULL, 0, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // some error
} 

// create event and associate it with the socket
m_SocketEvent = WSACreateEvent() ;
if(m_SocketEvent == WSA_INVALID_EVENT)
{
    // some error
}
// associate only the following events: close, read, write
if(SOCKET_ERROR == WSAEventSelect(m_Socket, m_SocketEvent, FD_CLOSE+FD_READ+FD_WRITE))
{
    // some error
}

// connect to a server
int ConnectRet = WSAConnect(m_Socket, (SOCKADDR*)res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) ;
if(ConnectRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // some error
}
```

And then, whenever I try to send some data over the socket to a (UDP socket) destination that is not listening or not reachable I always get the FD_READ triggered:

```
char buf[32] ;  // some data to send...
WSABUF DataBuf;
DataBuf.len = 32;
DataBuf.buf = (char*)&buf;

DWORD NumBytesActualSent ;

if( SOCKET_ERROR == WSASend(m_Socket, &DataBuf, 1, &NumBytesActualSent,0,0,0))
{
    if(WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK) // non-blocking socket - wait for send ok ?
    {
        // handle WSAEWOULDBLOCK...
    }
    else
    {
        // some error
        return ;
    }
}

int ret = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &m_SocketEvent, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE) ;


if(ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents ;
    ZeroMemory(&NetworkEvents, sizeof(NetworkEvents)) ;
    if(SOCKET_ERROR == WSAEnumNetworkEvents(m_Socket, m_SocketEvent, &NetworkEvents))
    {
        return ; // some error
    }
    if(NetworkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)  // Read ?
    {
        if(NetworkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_READ_BIT] != 0)  // read not ok ?
        {
            // some error
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE("Read Event Triggered ! - Why ? ? ? ? ? ? ?\n") ;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or insights would be most appriciated !
Thanks,
Amit C.

Comment: Maybe that's the ICMP message you receive (i.e. Destination Unreachable)? Check the header, it's a place to start.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the header (how to do that) ?                                                            I tried calling WSARecv to read data in this situation but got error 10054 ("... connection was closed..."), using ioctlsocket with FIONREAD I get 1 - meaninng I got 1 byte available for the socket to receive - but again WSARecv fails.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to inspect what really happens is to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture packets. I do not have Windows PC nearby to provide you a complete example, but my guess is that this is a normal behaviour - you try to send UDP datagram, it gets dropped by a router (host not found) or rejected by a server (socket closed); an ICMP message is sent back to inform you about the failure, which is what you receive and get an event for. Since there is no actual user data, underlying stack translates ICMP message and provides you an appropriate error message via *WSARecv()* return code. The "false" FD_READ event is necessary since UDP is connectionless protocol and there are no other means to inform about a network state. Simply add error handling for *WSARecv()* and your code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used Wireshark and did find that an ICMP message is delivered to my application in the situation I described.

Comment: Still, It seems a bit strange to me that a UDP socket receives the "false" FD_READ (and 1 byte of data available with ioctlsocket) just to let it know that connection is down. It also complicates things since I'm trying to create a class for handling UDP communication (Init, send, receive etc.) and the user of that class will get a read-ready event and then fail trying to read the data; Or when two of these sockets communicate, then one is going down but the other is still sending and after a while a new socket communicates with the one sending data - this error will arise.

Comment: If so, I guess that's some of the drawbacks of message oriented socekts... And again thanks for your reply -it helped!

Comment: Glad I could help in some way. Socket programming is a different world with many unique aspects and rules of its own, so expect more strange things to discover.